# how do i manually configure a virtual directory in IIS

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I am trying to get an external visual studio solution working in my local copy of visual studio professional 2010. When I open the solution, I see an error message that the local IIS URL has not been configured and would I like to create a virtual directory. When I click yes, it says that the configuration failed and that I have to manually configure the URL. How do I do that? I took a guess and created a virtual directory in IIS and pointed its path to the Visual Studio .sln file but when I tried to re-open the .sln file I got the same error message. Here are the errors I am getting:

[image]

Here is what the virtual directory that I created manually looks like in IIS manager:

[image]

Do I need to somehow modify a config file to tell it where to find the virtual directory on IIS? Or will visual studio search the virtual directories on IIS to see if any point to the path of the .sln file I am trying to open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Start Visual Studio with an Administrator (if you can). Then VS can automatically create the Virtual Directory
2. Use IIS Manager and add an Application (right click on Default Web Site and choose Add Application...). Set an alias (the name of your application) and the path Points to the root directory of your web application)

Comment: where do I click in the directory structure to add the application?

Comment: is the root directory the folder that holds the .sln file or the one that holds the .csproj file?

Comment: the one that holds your Project file of the web. It contains the bin Directory with the dll.

Comment: when I set it to path\to\proj.csproj and then click "Test Settings" it says "invalid application path"

Comment: I suddenly started getting this same error and neither one of these suggestions fix the problem on my machine