# Hello, Im trying to open a project in visual studio but this warning keeps coming up. Do you know how can i solve this? Thanks

Tags: c#

Error: Cannot write configuration file

[image: Error: Cannot write configuration file]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i manually configure a virtual directory in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797199/how-do-i-manually-configure-a-virtual-directory-in-iis)

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd try going to the Web project's properties and create the virtual directory through that menu:

[image]

If that doesn't work, I'll refer you to this link on Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory